# solidity transaction error, The called function should be payable

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I want to write a contract using router from uniswap. But when swapping 1 token to another, I get an error

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

I attach the code from below. How can I fix the error ?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity =0.8.7;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IQuoter.sol";

interface IUniswapRouter is ISwapRouter {
    function refundETH() external payable;
}

contract SwapV1 {
  IUniswapRouter public constant uniswapRouter = IUniswapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);
  IQuoter public constant quoter = IQuoter(0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6);
  address public token1;
  uint24 public ownerFee;

  function setToken1(address _token1) payable external {
    token1 = _token1;
  }

  function setFee(uint24 _fee) payable external {
    ownerFee = _fee;
  }

  function convertToken1ToToken2(address token2) external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "Must pass non 0 ETH amount");

    uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 20; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    address tokenIn = token1;
    address tokenOut = token2;
    uint24 fee = ownerFee;
    address recipient = msg.sender;
    uint256 amountIn = msg.value;
    uint256 amountOutMinimum = 1;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;
    
    ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams(
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        fee,
        recipient,
        deadline,
        amountIn,
        amountOutMinimum,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96
    );
    
    uniswapRouter.exactInputSingle{ value: msg.value }(params);
    uniswapRouter.refundETH();
    
    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
  
  function convertToken1ToExactToken2(uint256 token2Amount, address token2) external payable {
    require(token2Amount > 0, "Must pass non 0 DAI amount");
    require(msg.value > 0, "Must pass non 0 ETH amount");
      
    uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 20; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    address tokenIn = token1;
    address tokenOut = token2;
    uint24 fee = ownerFee;
    address recipient = msg.sender;
    uint256 amountOut = token2Amount;
    uint256 amountInMaximum = msg.value;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;

    ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams(
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        fee,
        recipient,
        deadline,
        amountOut,
        amountInMaximum,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96
    );

    uniswapRouter.exactOutputSingle{ value: msg.value }(params);
    uniswapRouter.refundETH();

    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
  
  // do not used on-chain, gas inefficient!
  function getEstimatedToken1forToken2(uint token2Amount, address token2) external payable returns (uint256) {
    address tokenIn = token1;
    address tokenOut = token2;
    uint24 fee = ownerFee;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;

    return quoter.quoteExactOutputSingle(
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        fee,
        token2Amount,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96
    );
  }
  
  // important to receive ETH
  receive() payable external {}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.